# A little bit complex Threading issue in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, spring

This might be a little bit abstract, so I'm going to try to simplifly it all:

1. I run my Android App.
2. There's an Interceptor for every request over the network (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html)
3. This Interceptor checks if there's internet connection or not.
4. If there's no connection, it's displaying a tiny Dialog with a Button to "Retry" overlaying the Activity that triggered the Network operation; meanwhile, a Sleep on the thread is activated.
5. On Retry Pressed, it cancels the Sleep, recalls method `intercept`. Then go back to step 1.

**Issue:**

All network operations run on a Background Thread, but when I display the Dialog, System sets the Dialog to be on UIThread. 
So then, the callback method triggered by Dialog when "Retry" button is triggered, is not anymore the same original Thread.

So then, If I recall the method `intercept`, and there's no connection still, this all network operation will occur on UIThread, SO will the previously mentioned Sleep from step 5.

I've debugged everything, and I'm sure the issue I'm experiencing is correctly explained above, and it's related with those two threads.
The first time the `intercept` method is called, the following code:

```
Log.d( "Log", ""+(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) );
```

Is returning **false**.

The second time, it's returning **true**, and after few seconds of Sleep, Android complains about "UI Not responding" ( Obviously :) ).

**What do I want (Or I think I do)**

- On the first call to `intercept`, get the Thread:

  ```
  Looper.myLooper().getThread();
  ```
- On the second call, as now "I am" on UI Thread, somehow "send" this second call to be run on the previously `Thread`. If I achieve this, I'm so sure everything will work.

Note that I can't just create a new Background thread, because the AppFlow would continue.

**So the overall question is:**

**From an existing thread, can I retrieve it and use it to run some other code?**

Hope I've explained myself.

Feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Whoever voted negative and flagged - Isn't this question related to programming? Mmh.

Comment: Unless you are real familiar with the Looper you should stay away from it. Without code to see what exactly you're doing its hard to help but I'd say change your logic rather than try fix this. There's no need for  communication between threads here, if the network thread says there is no connection let it die, show the retry and start a new thread on the button press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue just changing method calls.

Before, I used to trigger the recursive call from the "UIThread", after Dialog was "accepted". So what I'm doing now is:

- Sleep the thread (set `hold = true`)
- Show dialog
- OnOKDialog -> set `hold = false`
- The thread continues and do the recursive call.

So this way, background thread do the recursive call, and not the UI Thread.

Easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

To send a message to a thread the classic approach is to use a thread safe queue of some kind (a blocking queue is often used but you probably don't want to block in this case as the thread has other stuff to do).

When you get to an appropriate point in the thread check the queue and then process the things in it.

When you want things done from that thread just post them to the queue.

Comment: Uhm. I'm not very used with Threading. Atm, I'm keeping the Thread that called the method for first time like `if ( null == originalThread )
  {
   originalThread = Looper.myLooper().getThread();
  }`, so now, what I should do is somehow, do something like: `originalThread.run( aRunnableObject )`. Any tips?

Comment: Just create a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html. In the first thread read stuff from the queue and process it. In anywhere else you like (including the first thread) just post stuff to the queue. No need to keep track of threads at all.